# The Boolean modifier is additive rather than removing mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms, geometry

I have tried to find a solution to my problem online, but nothing seems to be helping. I am trying to use the boolean modifier to cut complex shapes into my mesh, but it is merging the meshes rather than cutting one using the other. Any and all advice is appreciated. I have attached the file for your viewing.

I've already checked for doubles and inverted normals.
[image]

https://we.tl/t-DxevPVADhS

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you work with a lot less subdivisions, and use Smooth shade to hide the hard edges (Right Click -> Shade Smooth). I reduced your number of subdivisions to 1 and the Boolean worked fine, you'll also need to apply the Mirror modifier first.

Also, try changing the geometry of that concave section (the top part of the "cutter") as it's producing very fine geometry when subdividing, I assume that was the problem here.

Comment: I know the mirror modifier does not have to be applied because I've used the method before. I also wonder why subdivisions matter. I struggle with using shade smooth because sometimes I want sharp and smooth geometry. I do find it interesting that it is possibly the fine geometry of the concave section causing problems. I will look further into that.